# Как разместить строку под текстом?

Tags: css3, html5, позиционирование

В браузере строка с кнопками "Train Dev Test" встает в заголовок страницы, а нужно, чтобы располагался под текстом.

```css
.text p {
  font-family: 'Inter';
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: justify;
  line-height: 24px;
  color: black;
  position: absolute;
  width: 800px;
  height: 35px;
  left: 216px;
  top: 223px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-style: normal;
}

.buttons {
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-bottom: 200px;
}

.button1 {
  background: #8953FC;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 199px;
  height: 60px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 29px 100px 60px;
}

.button2 {
  background: #8953FC;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  width: 199px;
  height: 60px;
  left: 515px;
  top: 554px;
}

.button3 {
  background: #8953FC;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  width: 199px;
  height: 60px;
  left: 816px;
  top: 554px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="offer">
    <h1 class="title">Задания</h1>
    <div class="text">
      <p class="p1">
        1.RuMedDaNet <br>
        <br>Основная цель этой задачи — измерить способность модели "понимать" медицинский текст и правильно отвечать на уточняющие вопросы. Истинная медицинская модель искусственного интеллекта должна обладать всесторонними знаниями и "пониманием" различных
        областей, связанных со здоровьем. Частично такие способности можно проверить, оценив ответы модели на контекстно-зависимые вопросы. Пример задания состоит из контекста и связанного с ним бинарного вопроса. Цель модели правильно ответить на поставленный
        вопрос либо да, либо нет. Контексты собраны из широкого набора областей, связанных с медициной: терапия, физиология и анатомия человека, фармакология, биохимия и т.п. Вопросы сгенерированы и размечены асессорами. Выборка разбита на 3 части train/dev/test,
        содержащие 1308/256/512 примеров. Для оценки результатов используется метрика Accuracy.</p>

      <div class="buttons">
        <a class="button1" href="#">Train</a>
        <a class="button2" href="#">Dev</a>
        <a class="button3" href="#">Test</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: makgeeva.alla, вас не устроил ответ? Может, я неправильно понял, что вы спрашиваете?

Answer (score 0):

Замените в CSS тег p на класс .pl:

```
.text .pl {
    font-family: 'Inter';
    font-weight: 400;
    text-align: justify;
    line-height: 24px;
    color: black;
    position: absolute;
    width: 800px;
    height: 35px;
    left: 216px;
    top: 223px;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Это должно сработать.